# I have Windows 10. How do I set default to use Left speaker only?

Tags: audio, digital-audio

I am trying to play a split track DVD. I set it to Left speaker and after each song it resets itself to both.  How can I make it stay on Left and not switch?

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click the Speakers icon in the task tray [image] and select Playback Devices
2. Right click the sound device you are using (it should have a checkbox on it) and select Properties
3. Click the Levels tab
4. Click the Balance button
5. Adjust balance as necessary

Comment: This only mutes the right speaker, as opposed to choosing only the left one as mono. Stereo sounds that only go out on the right speaker cannot be heard. -1

Comment: @Gaspa79 I dont think you understood her problem.  She *wants* only one track of audio.

Comment: Oh right, my bad